# how to integrate properties defined on multiple rows using a data.frame or data.table long format approach

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, aggregate, data.table

I have been recently starting to use the data.table package in R. I find it super-convenient for transforming and aggregating data. One thing that I miss is how do you transform data that are defined on multiple rows? Do I need to reshape the data.frame/table in a wide format first?

Say you have the following data table:

```
dt=data.table(group=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),
              subg=c("f1","f2","f3","f1","f2","f3"), 
              counts=c(3,4,5,8,9,10))
```

and for each group you want to calculate the relative frequency of each subgroup (c1/(c1+c2+c3)) and other properties as a function of c1, c2 ,c3 (c1, c2, c3 are the counts associated to f1, f2 and f3).

I can see how transform the data table in a wide format and then apply the transformation. Is there any way to calculate this directly in the long format (ideally using the data table)?

In general the group and subgroup could be represented by multiple factors.

Comment: I find this question a bit vague/broad at the moment. What's c1, c2, c3? What's the operation you want to do? As general as it may be, for sake of a question/answer, you'll have to illustrate, what operation and with an example as to what your desired output should be (ex: for this relative frequency).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand OP correctly, you want smth like this:

```
dt[, {bigN = .N; .SD[, .N / bigN, by = subg]}, by = group]
```

or maybe (and very similarly) this:

```
dt[, {counts.sum = sum(counts); .SD[, counts / counts.sum, by = subg]},
     by = group]
```

Comment: For this particular case, I'd do it this way: `dt[, sc := sum(counts),by=group][, counts := counts/sc]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the data.frame, you can use `ddply` from plyr package (two-step approach):

```
dt1<-ddply(dt,.(group),transform, gcount=sum(counts))# gcount=sum of count for each group
>dt1
group subg counts gcount
1     a   f1      3     12
2     a   f2      4     12
3     a   f3      5     12
4     b   f1      8     27
5     b   f2      9     27
6     b   f3     10     27

dt2<-ddply(dt1,.(group,subg),transform,rel.count=counts/gcount) #rel.count=relative frequency
>dt2
  group subg counts gcount rel.count
1     a   f1      3     12 0.2500000
2     a   f2      4     12 0.3333333
3     a   f3      5     12 0.4166667
4     b   f1      8     27 0.2962963
5     b   f2      9     27 0.3333333
6     b   f3     10     27 0.3703704
```