# For/while loop optimization with d_ply

Tags: r, loops, split, plyr

I am running a custom function which produces and saves some plots for each line of a data.frame:

```
zz <- "chr  start end   name  max
chr11 66184332 66197785 NPAS4_CBP20 90
chr11  62666002 62683613 BC047540_CBP20 100   
chr1 9824542  9828548  MIR3687_CBP20  500
chr6  33239767 33259282 B3GALT4_Pol2   1000
chr20  244996112   245029580   HNRNPU-AS1_Pol2   450
chr20 62487823 62525914 ABHD16B_Pol2   370
chr12 121146198   121179996   ACADS_Pol2  90"

my.genes <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

That function has two steps one of which is slow (~40 sec) but needs only to be run one for each chr and then for each line of that chr. In pseudocode it would be something like:

```
for each chr createData
   for each nameInChr do somethingWithData.
```

My question is, how optimize this? Nested d_ply? Sort data.frame by chr and then some form of apply on the unique(mygenes$chr)?

I am sorry if this does not contain the actual function, but it is a long one and I think this is more a good practice/theoretical question. However, if needed I can add proper code.

**edit**

Here is the simplified function (plotGviz). As it is, I don't think the d_ply will work because it will run UcscTrack for every line (am I correct?). The ultimate goal is to run UcscTrack for each unique chromosome and then use that information to construct the plot for each gene (name). Both steps (UcscTrack and plotting) are time consuming but rationale is that by running the non-unique part of the code (that that applies to chr) first it will save time on the whole - that table is a fraction of what I have.

The functions inside the custom plotGviz cannot be optimized only the way I set them up.

```
################
### libraries ##
library(Gviz)
library(GenomicRanges)
library(GenomicFeatures)
library(data.table)
library("RColorBrewer")
#######################


d_ply(my.genes, .(chr, name), plotGviz)

plotGviz <- function(gene) {
   chr <- gene$chr
   mygene.start <- gene$start
   mygene.end <- gene$end
   mygene <- gene$name
   max.cov <- gene$max

#################################################
## this part runs only once for each unique chr
## UcscTrack is what takes most time

   ## Gene annotations ##
   knownGenes <- UcscTrack(genome=gen, chromosome=chr,
   track="knownGene",  trackType="GeneRegionTrack",
   rstarts="exonStarts", rends="exonEnds", gene="name", symbol="name",
   transcript="name", strand="strand", fill="#FF7F00", name="UCSC Genes", geneSymbols = TRUE, showId = TRUE)

   refGenes <- UcscTrack(genome=gen, chromosome=chr,
   track="refGene", trackType="GeneRegionTrack", 
   rstarts="exonStarts", rends="exonEnds", gene="name", symbol="name",
   transcript="name", strand="strand", fill="#FF7F00", name="RefSeq Genes", geneSymbols = TRUE, showId = TRUE)

   ## axis scale ##
   ideoTrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = gen, chromosome = chr)
   # plotTracks(ideoTrack, from = mygene.start, to = mygene.end)

   axisTrack <- GenomeAxisTrack(scale=0.25)


####################################
## now for each name in unique chr
######################

   ## construct tracks ##


   ## ChIP-seq coverage from BAM ##
   bamPol2 <- "~/bioinfo/srp_chip_seq/data/reads/merged_reads_CBP20line/Pol2.bam"
   bamInput <- "~/bioinfo/srp_chip_seq/data/reads/merged_reads_CBP20line/Input.bam"

  ## histogram
   bTrackPol2 <- DataTrack(range = bamPol2, genome = gen, chromosome = chr,
      name = "Pol2", type = "histogram", col.histogram="#984EA3",
      ylim=c(0,max.cov))

   bTrackInput <- DataTrack(range = bamInput, genome = gen, chromosome = chr,
      name = "Input", type = "histogram", col.histogram="#999999",
      ylim=c(0,max.cov))


   #################
   ## plot tracks ##

   pdf(paste("./plots/", mygene,"_cov.pdf", sep="")) 

   plotTracks(list(ideoTrack, axisTrack, bTrackCBP20, pTrackCBP20, bTrackPol2, pTrackPol2, bTrackInput, refGenes, bTrackRNAcov), from = mygene.start, to = mygene.end, fontfamily="Helvetica", background.title="white", col.title="black", col.axis="black")

   plotTracks(list(ideoTrack, axisTrack, bTrackCBP20, pTrackCBP20, bTrackPol2, pTrackPol2, bTrackInput, knownGenes, bTrackRNAcov), from = mygene.start, to = mygene.end, fontfamily="Helvetica", background.title="white", col.title="black", col.axis="black")
   dev.off()

   # plotTracks(list(axisTrack, refGenes, bTrackCBP20, pTrackCBP20, bTrackPol2, pTrackPol2, bTrackInput, bTrackRNA), from = mygene.start, to = mygene.end, fontfamily="Helvetica", background.title="white", col.title="black", col.axis="black")

   # head(displayPars(bTrackPol2))
}
```

**edit2**

My temporary solution using a for loop for the unique chr, creating the UcscTrack before sub-setting all names for each chr and a d_pply for the plotting. Basically spiting that big function in 2 piaces.

```
for (chrom in unique(my.genes$chr)) {
   print(paste("creating annotation for ", chrom, sep=""))

   ## Gene annotations ##
   knownGenes <- UcscTrack(genome=gen, chromosome=chrom,
   track="knownGene",  trackType="GeneRegionTrack",
   rstarts="exonStarts", rends="exonEnds", gene="name", symbol="name",
   transcript="name", strand="strand", fill="#FF7F00", name="UCSC Genes", geneSymbols = TRUE, showId = TRUE)

   refGenes <- UcscTrack(genome=gen, chromosome=chrom,
   track="refGene", trackType="GeneRegionTrack", 
   rstarts="exonStarts", rends="exonEnds", gene="name", symbol="name",
   transcript="name", strand="strand", fill="#FF7F00", name="RefSeq Genes", geneSymbols = TRUE, showId = TRUE)

   ## axis scale ##
   ideoTrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = gen, chromosome = chrom)
   # plotTracks(ideoTrack, from = mygene.start, to = mygene.end)

   axisTrack <- GenomeAxisTrack(scale=0.25)

   ## select genes in chromosome
   df.g <- subset(my.genes, chr == chrom)
   d_ply(df.g, .(name), plotGviz)
}
```

Comment: This is pretty impossible to answer with know what `createData` and `somethingWithData` are. I think a general answer is difficult when the issue is optimisation, because it will depend on the specifics of what is going on

Comment: Is this unacceptably slow then? You could try parallelizing this.

Comment: Step 1, the 2 calls of UcscTrack, take about 40-50 sec in total and the plotting adds another 20 sec (aprox). It acceptable as long as I don't make more than handfull of plots, but I am planning on expanding it. Any suggestions on parallelizing?

Comment: `plyr` makes it really easy. Use one of the backends for the `foreach` framework, then replace `d_ply` with `d_ply(..., .parallel=TRUE, .paropts=list(.packages=c("Gviz", etc.)))`. This PDF explains the first step (and a lot more that isn't directly relevant to using `foreach` and `plyr`): http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: Sometimes you can find a clever way to optimize things, but often it's just easier to throw more resources at the problem. Your way of approaching the problem with nested loops (in the form of `d_ply`) seems sensible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `data.table`, it's going to be faster than `plyr`. Here's the generic approach to your problem:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(my.genes)

dt[, .SD[, do_smth(), by = name], by = chr]
```

And here's an example of the above approach in a different SO question - [how to integrate properties defined on multiple rows using a data.frame or data.table long format approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110933/how-to-integrate-properties-defined-on-multiple-rows-using-a-data-frame-or-data/18111239#18111239)